# Update a URL using a variable - PHP

Tags: php

I would like to assign a variable into the PHP code, which will change my URL. For example

`$page = 'http://www.example.com/search-products?type=buildings&q=small&go=Go';`

Where q=small i would like to change to say q=big (using a variable)

I have assigned a variable within PHP but i am unable to get it to work?

for example 
`$q= 'big';`

`$page = 'http://www.example.com/search-products?type=buildings&q=$q&go=Go';`

The url does not however update - Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use strings with `"` and not with `'` if you're using variables in it.

`$page = "http://www.example.com/search-products?type=buildings&q={$parameter}&go=Go";`

Comment: Thank you both for your help much appreciated ! - yes it now works

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
$page = "http://www.example.com/search-products?type=buildings&q={$q}&go=Go";
```

Note: Single quotes don't work in this case.
If you use Single quotes, you see something like this :

```
echo 'q={$q}';
//Output => q={$q}
```